# Laravel Echo / Pusher authentication fails (403)

Tags: laravel-5.4, pusher, laravel-echo

Learning `Laravel` event broadcasting / `Echo` / `Vue` and playing around with [this tutorial](https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-a-laravel-chat-app-with-pusher/).

I keep getting `403` responses to authentication, and I suspect my lack of understanding on the `channels.php` routes is the issue. I am using `Player` model instead of `User` for `Auth` which works ok.

Event `ChatMessageSend`

```
class ChatMessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $channel;
    public $player;
    public $chatMessage;

        /**
         * Create a new event instance.
         * GameChat constructor.
         * @param $chatMessage
         * @param $player
         */
        public function __construct(ChatMessage $chatMessage, Player $player)
        {
            $this->channel = session()->get('chat.channel');

            $this->chatMessage = $chatMessage;

            $this->player = $player;
        }

        /**
         * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
         *
         * @return Channel|array
         */
        public function broadcastOn()
        {
            return new PrivateChannel($this->channel);
        }
    }
```

Listener `ChatMessageNotification` (default / empty)

```
class ChatMessageNotification
{
    /**
     * ChatMessageNotification constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ChatMessageSent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ChatMessageSent $event)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Controller `ChatController`

```
class ChatController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Send chat message
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function getMessages(Request $request)
    {
        return ChatMessage::with('player')
            ->where('progress_id', '=', session('game.progress.id'))
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
    }

    /**
     * Send chat message
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return array|string
     */
    public function sendMessage(Request $request)
    {
        $player = Auth::user();

        $message = $request->input('message');

        if ($message) {
            $message = ChatMessage::create([
                'player_id'   => $player->id,
                'progress_id' => session()->get('game.progress.id'),
                'message'     => $request->input('message')
            ]);
        }

        broadcast(new ChatMessageSent($player, $message))->toOthers();

        return ['type' => 'success'];
    }
}
```

Routes `channels.php`

```
Broadcast::channel(session()->get('chat.channel'), function ($player, $message) {
    return $player->inRoom();
});
```

And in my `Player` class

```
/**
 * A user can be in one chat channel
 */
public function inRoom()
{
    if ((Auth::check()) and ($this->games()->where('progress_id', '=', session('game.progress.id'))->get())) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

When a player logs in, I store in session a chat room id which I would like to use as channel.

My `vue` chat instance is

```
Vue.component('chat-messages', require('./../generic/chat-messages.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-form', require('./../generic/chat-form.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#toolbar-chat',

    data: {
        messages: []
    },

    created() {
        this.fetchMessages();

        Echo.private(chat_channel)
        .listen('chatmessagesent', (e) => {
            this.messages.unshift({
                message: e.data.message,
                player: e.data.player.nickname
            });
        });
    },

    methods: {
        fetchMessages() {
            axios.get(chat_get_route)
            .then(response => {
                this.messages = response.data;
            });
        },

        addMessage(message) {
            this.messages.unshift(message);

            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.$refs.toolbarChat.scrollTop = 0;
            });

            axios.post(chat_send_route, message)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

But I keep getting

```
POST http://my-games.app/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)
Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 403
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 403 /broadcasting/auth with Laravel version > 5.3 & Pusher, you need change your code in **resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js** with

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'your key',
    cluster: 'your cluster',
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + YourTokenLogin
        },
    },
});
```

And in **app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php** change by

```
Broadcast::routes()
```

with

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
```

or

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']]); //if you use JWT
```

it worked for me, and hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an idea to figure out whether your routes/channels.php file is doing as you expect. Maybe add some logging to see if that route gets called at all, and that your inRoom function is returning what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still needs an answer, this worked for me.
Add to your broadcastServiceProvider.php

```
Broadcast::routes([
'middleware' => 'auth:api']);
```

add to your channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function () {
    return Auth::check();
});
```

Comment: Im trying to do this with laravel breeze api sanctum session. I added the middle ware in the service provider, and it solved the 403 issue, but now returns 401 unauthenticated. Any tips?